# How can I load a data table after the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I would like to load data in a table but I would like to do this after the page loads.  The actual page has a table, a textbox, and a search button.  I was thinking ajax would help, but I am yet to find a good solution for my problem.  How do I do this? Javascript, Jquery or otherwise.

```
<table class="roundAll" >
   <tr class="titleRow">
     <th colspan="2">New Entries</th>
   </tr>                                 
   <%foreach(var item in Model.NewList) { %>
   <tr>
     <td><%=item.Date.ToShortDateString() %></td>
     <td><%=Html.ActionLink(item.id,"Redirect/" + item.id)%></td>                      
   </tr>
   <% } %>
</table>
<br/>
<table>
   <td><%= Html.TextBox("IdNum") %></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</table>
```

Comment: u can use .ajax function from jQuery to send a request to the server and later display the result.

Comment: Here is another article that discusses using jQuery Templates and AJAX to load some JSON data:

http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=604

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the page load completes run a jquery script which will load the data by using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and databind it with [jQuery Templates](http://blog.reybango.com/2010/07/09/not-using-jquery-javascript-templates-youre-really-missing-out/)